# Images in Phonegap Developer

Tags: cordova, geolocation, ripple

I am getting more familiar with Phonegap and with testing and building browser apps for the Android. One thing I can't get my head round though is images not showing in PG Developer on a phone (using same wifi as laptop) but they show fine once built and installed from APK. One example is the Google maps example on http://www.phonegap.co.in/tutorials/phonegap-geolocation-tutorial or similar. It works fine in Ripple, final build, but not connecting to the wifi on the phone using PG, I get an images not available error. The camera does work in PG but not the browser obviously. Feels like there should be a simple solution but haven't found one. How do I fix this?